# 413 request entity too large error in wordpress using apache?

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, httpd.conf

I have tried to upload .exe file in the wordpress admin, and I have given some codes for allowing exe upload. now I am able to upload .exe files lesser size(2MB), but I am trying to upload a 230MB file.  I have found similar question but no one has posted the answer or confirmation how this is resolved, We have tried to increase the below values in php.ini, but the error is same.

> upload_max_filesize   localvalue/512M master value/2500M,
>
> post_max_size   local value/512M  master value/300M.
>
> memory_limit    local value/512M  master value/512M

Kindly share your ideas or thoughts on this.If any one gone through the same issue kindly provide work around solution for this.

Comment: does `phpinfo()` confirms the changed size?

Comment: This values I took it from phpinfo file only

Comment: @peter the above mentioned values that I take it from the same method.